# Php read content change/added in website

Tags: php, javascript, api

I came across a situation which looks difficult as I am newbie. I searched on google but could not get any idea about it.
There is a site which provide users a facility to search for doctors in their area/state etc.

There may be a situation when number of doctors addresses can be increased on that site in any state. How can I know this new doctor added in that site, without visiting and searching in that site.

**In other words. Suppose you have a site. If you change your site content. How can I know that you change your site contents.**

I want to syncs the records with theirs, either daily or weekly because their databases changes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Suppose you have a site. If you change your site content. How can I know that you change your site contents.

Comment: If that website provides an API to access it's data you could easily write a script to see if anything new was added in a certain timeframe. It's possible even if it doesn't provide an API by parsing the site's content, tough more difficult. On the other hand, if you're just trying to compare a specific webpage to see if it changed, you just have to save an "original" version and compare it from time to time. It's hard to give a right or complete question here. You should try to build something first, and reach us if you find a specific difficulty along the way.

Comment: @imi without visiting the site? You can't - at least, there is no standardized protocol to be alerted of such changes. If you don't control the site, there is no way to do this without actually fetching the data.

Comment: @TomS. Thanks for a bit good suggestion. There is no API.

Comment: @Pekka. Let say If I fetch data with php. Can I know change then? Doctors record are in paging in that site.

Comment: you could maybe use a screen scraping tool and just keep a version and then compare the two versions.  This wouldn't be all that reliable but could possibly work.  BTW: I agree with @TomS try some things and then come back and ask for help if you need it.

Comment: @imi sure, but it's a huge task. You'd have to fetch and store old versions, compare them, and then discard all the *unimportant* changes... It's a lot of work to do

Comment: This is someplace in between "not a real question" and "off-topic".

Comment: Hah. All you people could not answer it. Only thing you can do is: vote down. You people could read change in any site. Any good developer can answer it like Zoltan Toth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP.

a basic example of usage :

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
    $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

You can also define a whole range of parameters, so it's easy to mimic a `POST` or `GET` - then you run the script regularly as a CRON job, save the results each time to a new file and [compare it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707505/how-to-compare-two-text-files-with-php) to the old one with PHP

Answer (score 2):

1. If *they* have some incentive to share updates with you (such as a business development arrangement), you can request read-only access to their database, an API interface, or that they deploy a script on their end to ping you whenever there is an update, or even send you updates as they come.
2. Most likely you just need to rescan their site on some interval and update your data accordingly.  You can avoid unnecessary processing and bandwidth overhead if you:

   1. Analyze the HTTP header returned by the page.  It may contain a "Last-modified" or "etag" which will help you identify whether the page has been changed since the last time you visited it.
   2. Use a CRC32() or md5() hash function on the contents loaded.  If it has changed at all it will produce a different hash.

Comment: Great. I have no incentive with them, no business. So your option 2 can be thinkable.

Comment: Be careful of copyright infringement.